# Angular 'childNodes' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to view a datatable [click here](https://datatables.net) when the view is loaded. At present I am receiving the error message `Type error : Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`, this is preventing my service data from loading. What generally causes this issue and how can it be resolved ?

```
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Original Balance</th>
        <th>Effective Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>New Balance</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="user in days | filter:query | limitTo: 1">
        <tr>
          <td>{{user['orginal-balance']['30-sept-15']}}</td>
          <td>{{user['effective-date']['30-sept-15']}}</td>
          <td>{{user['amount']['30-sept-15']}}</td>
          <td>{{user['action']['30-sept-15']}}</td>
          <td>{{user['new balance']['30-sept-15']}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

service

```
var promise = monthlyService.getmonths();
promise.then(function (data){
    $scope.months = data.months;
});
```

Controller

```
.controller('policyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.summary').matchHeight();
        $('.statements').responsiveTabs({
          startCollapsed: 'accordion'
        });
        $.ReStable({
          rowHeaders: false,
          maxWidth: 1024,
          keepHtml: false
        });
        $(".sortable").DataTable({
          "order": [[0, "desc"]]
        });
        if ($('.portal-body').children('.policy-block').length > 1) {
          $(".policy-block").addClass("multiple");
        }
    });
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
```

Comment: are you including full jQuery in the page, or just relying on JQLite that comes with Angular?

Comment: Full jQuery, additional i started with just Jquery and slowly transformed the site into angular, i've managed to get most things to work, other than this function. I've never come across this error before ?

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle/plunker? This reason might be you are trying to manipulate dom indirectly while angular is on the compile and linking phase.

Comment: as @Saad said I agree with him, the error has to do with the fact that the DOM (Document Object Model) is being altered indirectly, by a Controller, during the compile and linking phase. The alteration of the DOM throws the internal tree-walker out of whack and we end up referencing an undefined node. If you can make a plunker/fidddle it would be easy to diagnose the problem